# Python with different instantiation

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have the class like below,

```
class Tes:
    def __init__(self,*coefficients):
        self.coefficients = list(coefficients)

a = Tes((1,2,3))
```

How can I modify it to make it accept an instance of the same class for constructor.

```
a = Tes((1,2,3))
b = Tes(a)
```

Comment: Please define "same"

Comment: That is: `(a == b) is True` or `(a is b) is True`. These expressions are quite different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the first item of `coefficients` is an instance of `Tes` first, and if so, make a deep copy of its `__dict__` attribute into the current object's `__dict__` attribute to effectively clone the given `Tes` object:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class Tes:
    def __init__(self, *coefficients):
        if isinstance(coefficients[0], Tes):
            self.__dict__ = deepcopy(coefficients[0].__dict__)
        else:
            self.coefficients = list(coefficients)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy method instead?

```
class Tes:
    def __init__(self,*coefficients):
        self.coefficients = list(coefficients)
    def copy(self):
        return Tes(*self.coefficients)

a = Tes((1,2,3))
b = a.copy()
```

Comment: OP clearly states they want to pass an instance of their object as an argument to the constructor. FWIW I think this is a nice solution, but I think you should at least add your rationale (why implement a copy method vs what OP wants to do).

Comment: Rational is easy: it's simple, clear and achieves the exact same result. Not neglecting Argument by Popularity fallacy, having copy() methods is also a very common design choice... This looks like an XY problem, so sticking to the literal question asked by OP may not necessarily give the most useful answer...

Answer (score 0):

You could just get the objects attribute and pass it into `b`

```
class Tes:
    def __init__(self,*coefficients):
        self.coefficients = list(coefficients)
    def display(self):
        print(self.coefficients)
a = Tes(1,2,3)
a.display()
#star = unpack 
b = Tes(*a.coefficients)
b.display()
```

**output**

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: You'd want to unpack, `b = Tes(*a.coefficients)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky, and wouldn't work if you tried passing both an instance AND multiple arguments, but this will do what you want:

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, *coefficients):
        if len(coefficients) == 1 and type(coefficients[0]) == Test:
            self.coefficients = coefficients[0].coefficients
        else:
            self.coefficients = list(coefficients)
```

```py
In [9]: a = Test(1, 2, 3)

In [10]: b = Test(a)

In [11]: a.coefficients
Out[11]: [1, 2, 3]

In [13]: b.coefficients
Out[13]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: You could also modify this to take an arbitrary number of instances of `Test` by simply checking if ALL elements from the coefficients `tuple` are of the `Test` type, and then you could just extend `self.coefficients`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```py
class Tes:
    def __init__(self, *coefficients):
        if isinstance(coefficients[0], Tes):
            instance = coefficients[0]  # type: Tes
            self.coefficients = instance.coefficients
        else:
            self.coefficients = list(coefficients)


a = Tes((1, 2, 3))
b = Tes(a)
```

The idea is to check the class of the first positional argument, and if it happens to be a `Tes`, to take its `coefficients` attribute instead of using the original one from the arguments.